# How to avoid inserting headers to a file on Server Restart using log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

I am reading a header from a text file and adding it to file using log4j. 
The header is getting inserted successfully but it inserts header on every restart of my application, but I want the header to be inserted only when the file is created. I am using DailyRollingFileAppender, this would roll every midnight creating a new file.

I am overriding the getHeader method from PatternLayout class to add header to a file.

Can anyone help me out in inserting header only once (i.e. only when file is created)?

```
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender=com.logger.ErrorFile
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender.File=${logdir}/Error.log
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender.layout=com.logger.header.ErrHeader
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution.
What I am doing is I am overriding the setFile() method of log4j.FileAppender and there I have added the logic of inserting header only when the file is empty.

This works perfectly. But I am not sure is there any better solution for the same.

Comment: I think that your solution is the better!

Answer (score 4):

Im having the same problem, can you please post the code or an example of the logic you implemented when overriding the setFile method, in order to avoid the insert of header on every restart of the application.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** I figured our how, here is my implementation:

```
public class RegisterRollingFileAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender {

    @Override
    public synchronized void setFile(String fileName) {
        // Your logic goes here
        super.setFile(fileName);
        File f = new File(super.getFile());
        RegisterPatternLayout layout = new RegisterPatternLayout();
        if (f.exists()) {
            if (f.length() == 0) {
                super.setLayout(layout);
            } else {
                PatternLayout p = new PatternLayout();
                p.setConversionPattern("%m%n");
                super.setLayout(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where **RegisterPatternLayout layout** = *My custom layout class* I constructed overriding `getHeader()` method.

Anyway, I would like to see your implementation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Victor's solution is good, but there is one flaw, for example,
if RollingFileAppender is configured, so apparently you want to write header in each of the rolling file. However @override setFile will only insert one header into old file even if old file gets rolled over and new file is created.

I found a solution from this discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.programmer/MKl0MT5gePo), its suggestion is to override writeHeader() method. This writeHeader has modifier protected, so we need to create ErrorFile inside org.apache.log4j package

```
package org.apache.log4j;

public class ErrorFile extends DailyRollingFileAppender {
    @Override
    protected void writeHeader() {
        File f = new File(getFile());
        if (f.length() == 0) {
            super.writeHeader();
        }
    }
}
```

In your log4j.properties, change from

```
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender=com.logger.ErrorFile
```

to

```
log4j.appender.ErrFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.ErrorFile
```